# How to edit Windows 7 context menu to execute some file operators?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, contextmenu

As tittle, for example, I want:

1. Make a backup of current file (xcopy file.txt file.txt.bak)
2. Rename current file to file.txt.bak (mv file.txt file.txt.bak)

Thanks